# How can I launch wsadmin in background on websphere 8.5.5?

Tags: websphere, monitoring, wsadmin

I'm working on websphere 8.5.5 and I want to monitore the used memory of an application server. So I'm using wsadmin tool and it generates the data from jvmruntimeModule (PMI).

When I launch wsadmin in command line, it takes 2 minutes to answer, so I can't generate data every minute or 30 seconds for example.

Do you know a way to have the process wsadmin running in the background so that it will not constantly be restarted ?

Thanks a lot
Regards
Fatiha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `wsadmin` tool makes use of Python, you can use the `sleep` function.

```
import time
#wsadmin commands go here
time.sleep(30);
#Sleep for 30 seconds
```

You can use a loop to run it as long as you need.The specifics of the implementation are up to you.

Comment: @FatihaE. The standard procedure on Stack Overflow is to use votes to show your appreciation. If an answer is useful to you, upvote the answer. If an answer completely resolves your problem, mark it as accepted. This grants reputation to the folks who write the answers. Accepting an answer also improves your acceptance rate, which makes it more likely that others will answer your questions in the future. :-)

Comment: Ok XSurgent, I have already voted, and now I have marked the answer as accepted. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not run the wsadmin once, passing in your commands in a file and then put a sleep that way you only need to initiate the wsadmin JVM once.

e.g   ./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f myscript.py

Then your myscript.py file can have something like this:

```
import sys
import time
from org.python.modules import re

count=99
while count > 0 :
    <Do your PMI collection here>
time.sleep(60)
```